# Pc doesn't boot

Tags: desktop-computer

Windows 10 doesn't boot ( it does in safe mode) getting whea uncorrectable error. Tried changing ram, using different hard disk changing video card nothing helped. And reinstalled windows to 3 those HDD's, after reinstalling when it's getting devices ready getting same error. Bios default. 
Can it be processor or motherboard fault if it boots on safe mode? 
And if anyone have any ideas I could try please tell me.
Everything happened while playing player unknowns battlegrounds.

Comment: If you have reinstalled Windows 10 three different times and it doesn't work, that means you have a hardware issue, that only exist when you load the device driver for it.

Comment: But it boots in safe mode? And I have changed everything expect motherboard and cpu, doesn't make sense. It shouldn't boot at all

Comment: Safe mode loads a limited set of drivers, so the problem driver/device (*or service*) is going to be one not loaded during safe mode.

Comment: Changed CPU same thing my CPU works on other PC. So I guess it's mother board. But bios works updating it works, im lost. And mother board is not even year old